# Delete internal geometry for bezier curve converted to mesh

Tags: geometry

I have a bezier curve that I converted to a mesh.   It has overlapping faces and internal geometry because of the extruding I did.

I tried to create cuts at the overlapping faces with intersect knife self intersect/cut and then select all internal faces.   But it doesn't seem to work.   How can I delete all the internal geometry that was created?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? It's hard to know what you are seeing/asking.

Comment: Added to the original post

Comment: It can really be simpler to retopo the model and shrinkwrap it onto the original; repairing that mesh can quickly become much harder task

Comment: Hmmm, haven't ever used the shrinkwrap constraint.  Studying it, seems like it could work.

On the select internal faces, seems like the definition of an internal face is not what I have.   Selecting non-manifold also doesn't seem to work.